# remove tag from the value jquery

Tags: jquery

I have:

```
<input type="hidden" name="some[]" value="some1">
<input type="hidden" name="some[]" value="some2">
```

How can I remove the input whose value is "some1" with jquery?

Comment: jQuery's documentation is quite good, you should have a look at it. For example, the [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) or [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('input[value="some1"]').remove();
```

should work.

There was a time when the `""` around `some1` caused issues in some browsers, I'm not sure if this is still the case. If it doesn't work, take the double quotes out.

Comment: Quoting the value is mandatory. *Edit:* Apparently not any more: *"**value** An attribute value. Can be either an unquoted single word or a quoted string."*

Answer (score 0):

`$('input[value=some1]').remove()` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery uses CSS selectors, and here [W3 CSS Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) you can check what is selector for your needs.

So, this should work:

`$('input[value="some1"]').remove();`